# Authorization doesn't work.

Tags: web, authorization, bitrix

2 weeks ago an authorization on all my sites stopped working. There is no record on log file. Looks like a page is just refreshing, but there is no access. Previously, everything worked fine. 
There alco a console message:

> This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure 
>   context. A warning has been added to the URL bar.

In this time there is an access to CMS site's administration application

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. Reset all browser cache
2. Try in different browsers (FF, IE and etc)
3. Write the authorization script using the API and run it at the root.